# how to automatically deploy a code to ecs in AWS pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services

how to automatically deploy a new code to ECS in AWS pipeline?
Source & Build stages in pipeline work well, but Deploy stage cant be executed, it runs for an hour, then finishes with error (timeout).
I need to manually stop docker container on EC2 (ECS), after that Deploy stage will work.
I m using Free tier, is there any limitation for codepipeline and ecs?

Comment: "finishes with error" what error? Sadly your question lacks any relevant details.

Comment: @Marcin there is a timeout error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to answer with so little details.

Do you use dynamic port mapping? If not, it could be that your ECS task is trying to use the same port as the one which is currently retiring.

Is the IAM Role used by CodePipeline able to do stuff on your ECS cluster?

Comment: no, i use port 80. 
Yes, IAM role can do stuff on ecs, because as i wrote above if i stop container manually, deploy stage works. Maybe there is a problem with Task Placement.

Comment: So, you expose your app on `:80`, but this port should be dynamically mapped on the EC2 instance. So you would have something like `:32768` mapped on the `:80`. Is that the case? May be check that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html)?

Comment: Thx, it worked, issue was in a port, i set dynamic port mapping and Deploy stage worked. How can i configure a port to be 80 always?

Comment: You should not use static port in general. Let AWS handle that for you with Dynamic Port mapping.